# What is the difference between cetylpyridinium chloride and alcohol?

Tags: oral-health, mouthwash, rinsing-mouth

I see that some mouthwashes or rinses have cetylpyridinium chloride in them and some have alcohol. Is there much of a difference in their ability to kill germs? Thank you.